# How to extract text from Wordpress Visual Composer for search results

Tags: wordpress, search-engine

We are using Visual Composer (VC) to enter content into our pages and blog.
When using the searchWP plugin, we output the excerpt of the page using

```
<?php the_excerpt();?>
```

However, this outputs an excerpt of our page with the VC code included.

Is there a way to just filter out the text, thereby getting rid of the VC code? Please note that inserting a plain text excerpt on each page is not an option!

Perhaps somebody can recommend an alternative search plugin which solves this problem automatically? Important features are indexing of Advanced Custom Field relationship field content, multiple search engines and customizable results with keyword highlighted content extracts.

Thanks in advance for any help!